# How do I edit loaded module in memory?

Tags: python, reflection, python-2.x

Suppose I have a file

```
# func.py:

def function():
    print 'Hello'
    print 'World'
```

And I have another file in the same dir

```
# load.py:

import sys
import inspect
from func import function
```

I can now access the source of function via:

```
code = inspect.getsourcelines(sys.modules['function'])
```

Is there anyway I can edit the lines of the function to make if print:

"Hello There World" instead of just "Hello World"?

I would like to do this all in memory by editing the function in place. I am currently accomplishing the same effect by reading a source and editing it as I write it out to a temp file, and the importing the temp file, but I would like to avoid the external file altogether.

Comment: Self-modifying programs died in the '50s or so. What you want is a function that accept an argument.

Comment: What is the final goal? There's probably a better way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't actually edit the function in place, but it does replace the function on that module with a new function without a temporary file (which may be good enough):

```
import inspect
import func

code = inspect.getsourcelines(func.function)
lines = code[0]
lines.insert(2,"    print 'There'\n")

exec ''.join(lines)
func.function = function
```

Comment: Did you mean function = ''.join(lines)?
And that would be useful, but the function is now a string. I need it to remain a <function> object because later I'm going to need to reference it from sys.modules['function']

Comment: `exec` executes the string, i.e. the full function definition.

Answer (score 0):

Are you think of [monkey patching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch) instead of actually replacing that code.

```
  import func

  func.function()

  def monkey_boy():
      print "Monkey Boy"

  func.function = monkey_boy

  func.function()
```

gives:

```
Hello
World
Monkey Boy
```

Comment: Yes, I'm basically monkey patching, but I don't want it executed right now. I want to edit/replace whatever so that later on I can call it in the same way

Answer (score 0):

You want a function with arguments:

```
def function(greeting='Hello', target='World'):
    print greeting, target
```

In the other file:

```
function()   #prints Hello World

function(target='To The World')  #prints Hello To The World
```

If this is not what you want, then explain what is the *use case* because I'm pretty sure you are going to create a **huge** design flaw doing what you described.

As I stated in a comment self-modifying programs were used in the '40s/'50s, but not after that.